# Singleton design pattern, static access non static?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I think to a common Singleton Design Pattern:

```
public class Singleton{

   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton(){}

   public static Singleton getInstance(){

    if(instance==null)
       instance=new Singleton();

   return instance;

   }
}
```

as far as I know, costructors are NON static methods because they can use the context reference "this" (which is forbidden in static contexts). On the other hand, static members can access only static members.

So how is it possible that static member getInstance() is accessing the non static member constructor?

Comment: Constructors can be called from anywhere.( Well here, since it's singleton - so anywhere from inside the class)

Comment: Here, a new instance is created. It is not like we called `Singleton()` (like we would call another method) within your static method. Which would be impossible of course.

Comment: *costructors are NON static methods*. Constructors are constructors. Methods have a return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see an object creation like `new Singleton()` you must distinguish the `new` operator from the constructor code or to be more precise the initializer code.

The `new` operator is "*like*" a static method call. It doesn't need an instance of an object, because it creates one.

The constructor code is more "*like*" an instance method, except that it has no return type. But it can access the `this` reference.

At least you will see the difference when you dive into the generated bytecode. The `new` operator will lead to this bytecode instruction.

```
NEW yourpackage/Singleton
```

This instruction only creates the object in memory. See [jvms-6.5.new](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.new)

After the object is created it is initialized by executing the initializer code. In the bytecode it looks like:

```
INVOKESPECIAL yourpackage/Singleton.<init> ()V
```

The initializer code is more than only the constructor code. It invokes the super class's initializer and initializes instance fields.

Also see the [java virtual machine specification 2.9](http://At%20the%20level%20of%20the%20Java%20Virtual%20Machine,%20every%20constructor%20written%20in%20the%20Java%20programming%20language%20(JLS%20%C2%A78.8)%20appears%20as%20an%20instance%20initialization%20method%20that%20has%20the%20special%20name%20%3Cinit%3E.%20This%20name%20is%20supplied%20by%20a%20compiler.%20Because%20the%20name%20%3Cinit%3E%20is%20not%20a%20valid%20identifier,%20it%20cannot%20be%20used%20directly%20in%20a%20program%20written%20in%20the%20Java%20programming%20language.%20Instance%20initialization%20methods%20may%20be%20invoked%20only%20within%20the%20Java%20Virtual%20Machine%20by%20the%20invokespecial%20instruction%20(%C2%A7invokespecial),%20and%20they%20may%20be%20invoked%20only%20on%20uninitialized%20class%20instances.%20An%20instance%20initialization%20method%20takes%20on%20the%20access%20permissions%20(JLS%20%C2%A76.6)%20of%20the%20constructor%20from%20which%20it%20was%20derived)

> At the level of the Java Virtual Machine, every constructor written in the Java programming language (JLS §8.8) appears as an instance initialization method that has the special name . This name is supplied by a compiler. Because the name  is not a valid identifier, it cannot be used directly in a program written in the Java programming language. Instance initialization methods may be invoked only within the Java Virtual Machine by the invokespecial instruction (§invokespecial), and they may be invoked only on uninitialized class instances. An instance initialization method takes on the access permissions (JLS §6.6) of the constructor from which it was derived

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are not methods. Static methods are associated with a class, and non-static methods are associated with instances of that class. You cannot call non-static method from a static method because there is no instance associated with the static method. You can call constructors from static methods because constructors are associated with classes, not instances.

Constructors can use "this" reference only after the object is instantiated, i.e. after the constructor is called.